How do I pin the calculator to my home screen?
I find it handy to have a calculator on my phone, but the way I have to launch it is anything but handy. It is not on my home screen (or any that come if I swipe to the side) nor on the set of screens I get from swiping up and then to the side. It is not in any of the little "clumps" of apps labelled Samsung, Google, etc.
If I swipe up and use the search, I get one result but it's not the app it's the app info. Nevertheless, if I go to the app info down at the bottom there is an Open button and I can thus launch it and use it. I have tried long pressing on the app when it's running, on this app info screen, and just about everywhere else in the hope of finding a Pin To Home option, but no. I also found it in the store but that didn't help.
What am I missing? How can I have a calculator I can launch with like one swipe and a click, no typing?

You should probably edit your post to include make/model/OS version and if you are using a custom home screen app. However you should be able to add the app to your home screen. You may want to include screenshots of the calculator app icon/add a store link or mention if the calculator app came with the phone.

Most launchers allow to add an app to home screen by pressing and holding the app icon in the search result and then move it up until the home screen appears where you can drop it.

@Robert I know, but the app icon isn't in the search result. Only an entry for the app info, and pressing and holding that does nothing

@MorrisonChang everything is super ordinary. It's a samsung and the calculator came with it. I am not using custom anything. Yes, I know I should be able to, that's why "why can't I? What's going on?" is my question.

Then may be you have uninstalled or disabled calculator app. Google Android devices have an calculator app preinstalled, mostly this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calculator

I found it in the store with a green and white icon and there is an Uninstall button. So it is installed. Plus, i can run it albeit by a roundabout process. Therefore it is not uninstalled or disabled. I just can't get it pinned to my home screen.

Strange, okay if you install Robert's link can you add Google's calc to your home screen (and do everything else normally). Otherwise a few suggestions to try: (1) shutdown and restart your phone. While it shouldn't do anything perhaps homescreen app is in a bad state. (2) double check all nested folders in your homescreen for the green/white calc app as it is already in your homescreen just badly placed (and you can only have one of same app at a time)(3) if your green/white calc app doesn't have important data, delete and reinstall and then see if you can pin it/etc.

I have established what happened (but have no idea how) and have fixed it.
The calculator was among the 3 apps listed as "hide from home screen". This seems to be a many-click action, so I can't imagine I ever did it accidentally, but anyway. I removed it from that section and now when I search on the swipe-up screen, the app itself (not just its info) appears so I can launch it, or pin it to Home (which I have done.)
If someone was planning to hide an app as part of concealing an activity, they should know you can still find the app by searching both on the phone and in the store, and see that it is installed. But more importantly to me, if searching for an app returns only its info rather than the app itself, check the list of hidden things.
Settings, Home Screen, Hide Apps on Home and Apps screens.
My problem is now solved.

Just to confirm on my Samsung Galaxy S9 stock home screen app running Android 10, I was able to long press on a empty home screen page, select "Home screen settings", scroll down to bottom and find the 'Hide apps' configuration. While on a Google Pixel 6a stock home screen Android 13 the closest I could find is under Suggestions which limits an apps search visibility but not remove icons.
